# My function is running when page loads, but I only want it to run when a selected area is picked

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabletop.js

I am making a random quote generator with JavaScript and Tabletop.js. When my page loads, the function to pull a quote and generate from my spreadsheet is   automatically initialized. I don't want it to generate a new quote unless the page/area is clicked.

BTW, it's a vulgar page, basing it off of greatfu**ingstartupadvice.com

Here is the codepen page:

http://codepen.io/JonLangel/pen/kXdmqP?editors=1010

Here is the JS from the Codepen page:

```
var my_spreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sX822Oiga0j0eHC8PvegRo6W8GGC0a28nVgnvSsOqo/pubhtml';

var sheet_data;

function init() {
  Tabletop.init( { 
    key: my_spreadsheet, 
    callback: saveData,
    simpleSheet: true
    });
}
function saveData(data, tabletop) {
  sheet_data = data; 
  newQuote(); 
}

 function newQuote() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sheet_data.length));

    $("#advice").html(sheet_data[randNum].Advice).addClass('animated     zoomIn').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass();
        });
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {

   init();

   $('.container').onclick(function(){
     newQuote();

 }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In start of page You are initialising **Tabletop**, but in callback of init:

```
callback: saveData //saveData is callback of init
```

And code this function:

```
function saveData(data, tabletop) {
  sheet_data = data; 
  newQuote();  //here You have newQuote called
}
```

Remove **newQuote()** from saveData and quote will be not generated at page load

```
function saveData(data, tabletop) {
  sheet_data = data; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your calling saveData as a callback of Tabletop.init andsaveData is calling newQuote

You should simply remove the call to newQuote in saveData

Comment: When I do that, it no longer allows me to get any new quotes when clicked. Thanks for the quick response btw!

Answer (score 0):

Ur calling newQuote() in ur callback.

Remove newQuote() from ur saveData function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click events handler and triggers click event after

```
 $(".newquote").click(function(){
           $.post("your.php".function(){
             //code logic
          })
     })
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using .onclick(); !

Answer (score 0):

You added a `saveData` in the callback of `Tabletop.init`.

When `Tabletop` has finished to be inited the method `saveData` is executed.

In the method `saveData` you have an explicit call to `newQuote()`.

Simply remove it:

```
function saveData(data, tabletop) {
   sheet_data = data; 
   //newQuote();  // Remove the call to newQuote();
}
```